# CentOS7 user authentication

Tags: centos, login

I've set up a VM in VBox 5.1.22 running CentOS7 Everything release. I've done some work in it and left to check some stuff on my host OS, Win7. After 10-15 minutes I checked the VM again and it went to a loop which says Authentication error, refreshing about every 0.75 seconds. I tried to type in my password, but every refresh erases the typed in text. Can't click on 'Log in as another user'. Tried to make an exact VM, it's doing the same thing. I never had these problems yet.
Tried to reboot, I only the cursor on a black screen.
Tried to google it, only find answers about remote logins.

It's a local VM, I just expect to login and continue my work. Can't access logs because I can't login.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems a display driver issue

Comment: May be. I bought a new monitor a few days ago so I'll try to run it on my laptop's screen tommorrow. Thanks! I'll post the results as soon as I try it out.